# How the condition 2='2' in sql query returns true?

Tags: sql-server

How the below query returns true for the conditions

```
Select * from Table_name Where 2='2'
```

and fails at

```
Select * from Table_name Where 3='2'
```

How the comparison works here?

Comment: Implicit conversion from `varchar` to `int`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx 2=2 is ever true but 3=2 never.

Comment: Thanks Tim, If i do not want implicit conversion?

Comment: If you don't want implicit conversion, why are you comparing varchar with int?

Comment: Dont  compare apples to oranges if you don't want that sql-server tries to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from Table_name Where 2='2'`

SQL Server will convert strings to integers in an integer context

So `2='2'` is always true. And `2='3'` isn't

Comment: While SQL Server does convert strings to integers in an integer context, you aren't really explaining why the context is integer.